# Combining regex awk and bc

Tags: bash, unix

I have a text file containing single line numbers such as "123 2345 432 487 11". I want to take logarithm (ln) of each number and save it as a text file. 
I tried but could not combine bc -l command and awk. Dou you know how can I implement it?

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i = l($i) | bc -l }' text.txt
```

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly did not work?

Comment: awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i = l($i) | bc -l }' text.txt

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need `bc` since awk has a perfectly good "log" function:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print log($i)}' input.txt
```

If you want to see the values with more precision, use `printf` instead of print. Eg:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%.12f\n",log($i)}' input.txt
```

If you really want to use `bc`, you can do this without `awk` by fabricating the input to `bc` with, for example, the shell `printf` command (which is similar but not the same as the awk printf command; one big difference is that the shell command repeats the format until it runs out of arguments):

```
printf "l(%s);\n" $(<input.txt) | bc -l
```

or, if `input.txt` has a lot of data

```
xargs printf "l(%s);\n" <input.txt | bc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)system("echo l\\("$i"\\)|bc -l")}' input.txt > output.txt
```

Which outputs:

```
4.81218435537241749526
7.76004068088037973937
6.06842558824411031185
6.18826412308258979072
2.39789527279837054406
```